# kohana 3 auth code modify

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, kohana

I am using code straight out of a kohana guide for securing websites based on login credentials

The problem is the code seems to only check if a user is logged in and does not distinguish between role.

How would I modify this script to only allow the admin to access this action

In the base controller I have the code

```
public $assert_auth = FALSE;
public $assert_auth_actions = FALSE;


public function before()
{
parent::before();
$this->_user_auth();

}

protected function _user_auth()
{
$action_name = Request::instance()->action;
if (($this->assert_auth !== FALSE && Auth::instance()->logged_in($this->assert_auth) === FALSE)
|| (is_array($this->assert_auth_actions) && array_key_exists($action_name, $this->assert_auth_actions)
&& Auth::instance()->logged_in($this->assert_auth_actions[$action_name]) === FALSE))
{
if (Auth::instance()->logged_in())
{
Request::instance()
->redirect('');
}
else
{
Request::instance()
->redirect('admin/login');
}
}
```

in the controllers for the admin pages there is the code

```
public $assert_auth_actions = array(
'index' => array('login')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to note that the above code is for Kohana 3.0, for 3.1 and higher you should replace Request::instance()->action by Request::$current->action().

If you want all the same authorization requirements for all actions in the controller, then set $assert_auth to an array containing a list of all the roles one should have to access it.

If you want different authorization requirements for actions in the same controller then set $assert_auth_actions to be a multidimensional array. The first dimension should be the name of the action, the select a list of roles the user must have to access the action.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense!

I seem have to another problem now. I changed the authorized role to  admin and that did work in blocking the normal users.

The next thing I did was change a test users role in the roles_users tables to 2 for testing.

This user cannot be logged at all. Is the method for logging in an admin different than from a a normal user?

$user = ORM::factory('user');
$status = $user->login($_POST);

Comment: Does the test user have the login role?

Comment: Yes I setup the auth tables using the default schema
users, roles, roles_users

All of methods related to logging in / out / registering are working fine

The first thing I tried was simply changing the role from 1 to 2 in the roles_users table, and at that point the user can no longer login

The second thing I tried was modifying my registration code to save the user as role 2 which is the admin
`$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role')->find(1));`

Everything looks fine in the database, the user saved and the role_user saved, but I still cannot login with this user

Comment: sorry I meant to say I changed the  add role
`$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('role')->find(2));`

basically it seems the user cannot login when he has the admin role

Comment: Users can have many roles, Auth will only let them log in if the login role is in its set of roles. User X could have the following roles: login, admin, moderator, author, editor. So if you want a admin account which is able to log in it wil need BOTH the login AND admin roles.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help me. Works great now!